# Uncaught require_once(): failed to open stream

Tags: php

I'm having the following error when trying to require_one a file:

```
Uncaught require_once(../web/common/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I'm calling trying to make this require from a file that is inside a folder called 'tests' that's at the same level of the folder 'web'. 
From what I see, by using ../ I'm going to the same level of both folders, and then by calling /web... I was able to get to the file I need.

My folder structure is the following:

- web

  - common

    - config.php
- tests

  - dbTest.php

The require is called from dbTest.php

What's missing?

Comment: What? is your file that is using `require_once` function, in the same folder/level of the `config.php` or how it is? because I didn't understood what you said.

Comment: Is this running on linux, mac or windows?

Comment: What is your initiating file? You will have to consider relative path with respective to your starting/initiating file

Comment: On a side note, you should always use require instead of require_once unless absolutely necessary, it has much better performance. In most cases require_once is unnecessary because there is absolutely no chance of the file being included more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used is the path of the main file, not the path your include file 'dbTest.php.

To prevent issues like that, make it an absolute path using the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../web/common/config.php');
```

That ('magic') constant always contains the path of the file that uses it.